# Mongoose: Populate referenced SubDocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've the following schemas:

Occurence that references a competence in the CostCenter subdocuments competences.

```
const OccurrenceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  competence: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'CostCenter.competences',
  },
  ...
})
```

CostCenter where I've an array of subdocuments that can be ref by Occurence.

```
const CostCenterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  competences: [CompetenceSchema],
});
```

And finally the Competence.

```
const CompetenceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
});
```

When I try to populate the competence, I get "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"CostCenter.competences\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)".

```
const occurrence_list = (request, response) => {
  Occurrence.find()
    .populate('occurrence origin tag entity method priority competence')
    .then(occurrences => response.send(occurrences))
    .catch(e => response.send(e));
};
```

How can I possibly populate the occurrence when referencing a subdocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change your Occurrence model to this

```
const OccurrenceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
   competence: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'CostCenter' }
});
mongoose.model('Occurrence', OccurrenceSchema);
```

and CostCenter model:

```
const CostCenterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
   competences:[{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Competence' }],
});
mongoose.model('CostCenter', CostCenterSchema);
```

finally Competence model:

```
const CompetenceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
});
mongoose.model('Competence', CompetenceSchema);
```

To populate the competence from Occurrence, you can do so:

```
Occurrence.find({ your_query })
.populate('competence')
.then(occurrences => response.send(occurrences))
.catch(e => response.send(e));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But by doing this, I no longer have a competences subdocument but an array of competences (objectId) of their own collection, right? It's there any way to do the way that I was looking for? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. Can you try it first and see if the result is what you want? If it does not, can you give an example for what you want to have

Comment: I've tested it and it's really what I want, I believe. Basically I want to have cost centers that will have an array of unique competences. Those competences do not need to be stored on a collection, therefore I had them as a subdocument. By getting an occurrence, I want to be able to populate the occurrence with the name of it. I'm new to Mongo so I'm sorry for the bad explanation, I might be doing the wrong thing but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: It's good to hear that what you want. Let me know if you still have any question. If you want to learn more about MongoDB, this is a very good start https://www.udemy.com/mongodb-essentials-m and please mark mine as your answer, so I can receive some points :)))

Comment: I meant "not really", can you read the rest I said and tell me what you think? Perhaps what I was trying to do wasn't the best solution and yours is but let me know. And of course! :)